# Starting a netcat listener in new terminal window from python script

Tags: python, terminal, command

Total python noob here but trying to learn

I am trying to launch a new terminal window which is running a netcat listener on port 7777 from a python script.

I have tried...

```
import os

netcat = '--command \"nc -nvlp 7777\"'
print ("Starting listener on port 7777")
from subprocess import call
call(['xfce4-terminal', netcat])
```

and

```
from subprocess import call
call(['xfce4-terminal', '--command', '"nc -nvlp 7777"')]
```

but no dice. The second example will actually launch the terminal and look for a command, but doesn't execute the netcat "argument".

This seems to be caused by the fact that using `--command` requires my netcat argument to be surrounded by quotes.

Thanks in advance for all help

Answer (score 0):

After consulting a friend, we were able to find a solution that works.

We ended up putting the entire command to call the terminal with netcat into a variable and then passed that variable to the `call()` like so...

```
import os

netcat = 'xfce-terminal --command "nc -nvlp 7777"'
print ("Starting listener on port 7777")
from subprocess import call
call(netcat,shell=True)
```

You'll notice that we also had to use `shell=True` even though there was a warning against it.